# Ajuda com Requisições Ajax para pegar dados do BD

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou usando atualmente esse Código abaixo para buscar a página com os produtos referente a marca solicitada.

```
echo '<a class="marca" href="prod_index_marca.php?codmarca='.$res['codigo'].'">'.$res['nome_marca'].'</a>';
```

Mas estou tentando criar uma Requisição para que esse mesmo conteúdo abra em uma "DIV" sem que haja o Refresh, dessa forma abaixo:

```
echo '<a class="marca" style="cursor:pointer;">'.$res['nome_marca'].'</a>';

<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.marca').click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"prod_index_marca.php?codmarca=<?php $res['codigo'];?>",success:function(data){
            $('#visual').html(data);
        }});
    });
});
```

E a pagina "prod_index_marca.php" esta iniciando com seguinte PHP abaixo, e com todos os $res referente aos produtos da marca selecionada através de seu "codmarca":

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

$codmarca = $_GET['codmarca'];
$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codmarca = '$codmarca'");
$sql->execute();
foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res){
?>
```

Feito isso, verifiquei que a pagina esta sendo direcionada para a "DIV" desejada, porem não esta me trazendo os dados dos produtos referente a codmarca solicitada.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma ajuda para solucionar, ou mesmo indicar onde posso pesquisar como criar essa Requisição, ficarei muito agradecido.

Desde já agradeço a atenção ao meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua `url:"prod_index_marca.php?codmarca=<?php $res['codigo'];?>"` deve ser `url:"prod_index_marca.php?codmarca=<?php echo $res['codigo'];?>"`, está faltando a função `echo()`do php.

No `echo()` da tag `<a>` adicionei o campo `id=""` com o código da marca:

```
echo '<a class="marca" style="cursor:pointer;" id="'.$res['codigo'].'">'.$res['nome_marca'].'</a>';
?>
```

e no `Jquery` pega o id contendo o código para passar pelo `$.ajax()`:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.marca').click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url:"prod_index_marca.php?codmarca="+cod,
            dataType:"Json",
            success:function(data){
            $('#visual').html('');
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
                $('#visual').append(value);
            }
        }});
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado Smith, era isso mesmo que estava faltando...
Nada melhor que alguém de fora para ver os nossos erros, OBRIGADÃO mesmo...

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar @Murilo

Comment: Smith, me deparei com outro problema.
eu não estou conseguindo trazer os produtos referente a marca selecionada. Qualquer marca que eu clico, me traz sempre o mesmo produto. Teria como você ver onde estou errando? Mais uma vez OBRIGADÃO...

Comment: vou editar a minha resposta com uma possivel solução

Comment: editei, verifica ai se deu certo

Comment: Eu não uso "id" e sim "codigo", posso alterar para: `var cod = $(this).attr('codigo');`

Comment: O `id` em questão é um atributo da tag apenas, que vai contar o valor do código

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77040/discussion-between-murilo-and-wees-smith).

Answer (score 1):

Problema solucionado com a ajuda do Wees Smith.

Abaixo códigos funcionando.

O Código abaixo busca a página com os produtos referente a marca solicitada.

```
echo '<a class="marca" style="cursor:pointer;" id="'.$res['codigo'].'">'.$res['nome_marca'].'</a>';
```

A Requisição para abrir o conteúdo na "DIV" sem que haja o Refresh, ficou dessa forma abaixo:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.marca').click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({url:"prod_index_marca.php?codmarca="+cod,success:function(data){
            $('#visual').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

E a página "prod_index_marca.php" que mostra dentro da "DIV" o(s) produto(s) referente a marca selecionada ficou assim:

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";

    $codmarca = $_GET['codmarca'];
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho, menu, produto WHERE codmarca = $codmarca");
    $sql->execute();
foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res){
?>

<div id="prod" style="background-color:<?php echo $res['fundosite_cor']; ?>;width:33%; float:left; padding:10px 0;" class="center_prod_box">
    <div align="center" id="titulo" style="width:100%;">
        <?php echo $res['titulo']; ?>
    </div>
<div align="center" style="width:100%; height:130px; background-color:<?php echo $res['fundosite_cor']; ?>;">
    <div align="center">
        <a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>">
            <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/<?php echo $res['img01']; ?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div align="center" id="preco" style="width:100%;">
    <span style="">
        R$ <?php echo $res['preco']; ?>
    </span>
</div>                        
<div align="center" id="carrinho" style="width:100%;">
    <a href="prod_carrinho.php?acao=add&codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>">
        <img style="width:100%; max-width:20px;" src="img/carrinho.png" title="Por no Carrinho" />
    </a>
</div>                        
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Problema solucionado, e que possa ser útil para os amigos no futuro.